# Encrypted password generator for web site login for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, osx-mavericks

I would like to have password generator for logging in e-commerce site and It have to be encrypted all the time to pass the password even it's clipboard level. Is there an solution?

Comment: Due to urgent matter to keep secure my password. Because my internet account such google account is attacked by someone manytimes also seems be logged in. So, I wonder it could be tempest. So, I was looking for secure solution quickly. Anyway, Please remove and Than k you, Awal Garg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last pass - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd. This will do even more than that.

Personally used, tested and happy with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for telling me. It looks good. I will use this.

Comment: I am glad I helped...